# Compare String with binary and getting a result back

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| malwareName | sequence             |
+-------------+----------------------+
| omega       | 01110101111110110111 |
| test2       | 2                    |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

where malwareName is a varchar and sequence is a binary.

When i do "Select * from malwareTable where sequence = '2', I get an empty set. Why and how can i get:

```
+-------------+----------------------+
| malwareName | sequence             |
+-------------+----------------------+
| test2       | 2                    |
+-------------+----------------------+
```

when I want the sequence of 2 ?

Comment: Maybe try it without the singles quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Passing quotation marks around the number treats it as a string. To have it treated as an integer, you simply need to omit the quotation marks around the integer value:

`Select * from malwareTable where sequence = 2`

Comment: how will i be able to check if the binary value of 2 is in a string, lets say "I will have 2 hotdogs" ?

Comment: That's rather a different question, but you would use the `LIKE` clause, with the target enclosed in percentage signs. As in `SELECT * FROM malwareTable WHERE sequence LIKE '%2%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You said the sequence is a binary. I think '2' is a varchar, so because of binary and varchar is not equal. then you get an empty set... maybe?

So You have to write Query like

`SELECT * FROM malwareTable WHERE sequence = 2`